# 'Dbgview.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file

Tags: visual-c++

I am getting above error for below program. DebugView.bat file contains debugview.exe

```
enter code here

int main()
{
    STARTUPINFO si = { sizeof(STARTUPINFO) };
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    wchar_t cmdline[] = L"cmd.exe /C \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\SanDisk\\CVF_2.0_x64\\DebugView\\DebugView.bat\"";

    if (!CreateProcess(NULL, cmdline, NULL, NULL, false, CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT,NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
    {
        std::cout << GetLastError();
        abort();
    }

    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
}
```

Comment: Why it is voted -1 ??? I did lot of R&D for this error, it didn't find anything related to this post and after that I posted in stack overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the error message is indicating that debugview.exe can't be found. So, make sure it is in the path. You can also edit DebugView.bat to add the folder to where debugview.exe can be found.